# TinyMapper : Does calling TinyMapper.Bind<TTarget, TSource>(); cause performance issues? Should it be called only once?

Tags: c#, tinymapper

I have an assembly that contains a class that maps objects from my Dal entities to Business objects.  This class maps a few different objects (Profile, Address, etc).  I am replacing the mapping-by-hand with TinyMapper.  In general:

1.List Mapping Method

```
public IEnumerable<TTarget> MapFromDal(IEnumerable<TSource> source){
    return source.Select(MapSingleFromDal);
}
```

2.Single Object Mapping method

```
public TTarget MapSingleFromDal(TSource source){
    //By hand mapping code.
}
```

In replacing mapping code with TinyMapper, where should I put my Bind statement?  Is it expensive to call often?
My first cut at this I just put this line in my MapSingleFromDal method:

```
TinyMapper.Bind<TTarget, TSource>();
```

So it gets called every time I map a single object.  This doesn't feel right, so I wonder where to put it.  Should it be in the constructor of this class?  It maps lots of objects, so should I just stack up the calls in the constructor like so?

```
TinyMapper.Bind<T1,S1>(); 
TinyMapper.Bind<T2,S2>(); 
TinyMapper.Bind<T3,S3>();
```

And what happens when I call `TinyMapper.Bind<T1,S1>();` again?  Is it expensive?

Answer (score 4):

`TinyMapper.Bind<TTarget, TSource>()` generates the mapping code, i.e. find all fields, properties then create IL code and finally creates an object with appropriate mapping method. So, yes it's expensive.

Try to call `TinyMapper.Bind` only once. [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/) is a nice place for register all bindings.

Another option: if your `Target` and `Source` types are simple, i.e. you don't use any ignore or special mappings. You call only `TinyMapper.Bind<TTarget, TSource>()` so you can don't call `Bind` at all and call `Map`. In this simple case, `Map` calls `Bind` and it's called only once.